# Upload data to simulated iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using `XCode 9.2` and I want "upload" a data - lets say a database - onto my simulator so that when I run the XCode proejct, the data is already on the device. How would I upload a data onto the simulator and how to I get the path to access it in the app?
Is it done through `XCode` or the `Finder`? I know that I can access all the simulators here `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` but how do I know which simulator is i.e. the iPad? How do I get the path to the data? And does it matter in which folder I put the data?

Comment: Why don't you use your data from the app's bundle?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Because I didnt know about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without messing around in the Finder by simply adding the files you want to your Xcode project and making sure they are included in the "copy bundle resources" build phase. Those files will then be available to your app at runtime from within the main bundle, and you can access them like this:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourfile", withExtension: "ext") {
  let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
  // process the data here
}
```

If you need read/write access to the files, you need to copy them from the bundle to the app's sandbox directories, e.g. to your "application support" directory.